# No touch events available when QGraphicsView is visible

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4, touch-event, qgraphicsview

I have an PyQt4 application which is deployed on a touch device. The central widget is a QTabWidget. All pushbuttons are touch enabled using the setAttribut() method. Now, the application shall get new functionality, which uses a QGraphicView component, which is placed on a new tab.

The As long as the graphic view is not visible, touch events are properly created and processed by the buttons. After the graphic view gets visible, no more touch events are available. Instead, every touch on the screen results in a MousePressEvent.

Which properties have to be set to not get touches as mouse press events only?

Comment: Qt4 has been unsupported for more than 6 years, and the last release was more than 10 years ago... If you want to get new functionality (and help), you should at least port it to Qt5.

Comment: @musicamante thank you for your response. Unfortunately the Environment the application is deployed in cannot be changed due to several old APIs of 3rd party suppliers. Unsure, when life cycle of current configuration ends.

Comment: Unfortunately, being Qt that old, it's very difficult to find help about this specific matter. When the last version was released, touch devices were not common as they are today, so it's possible that the touch support is somehow "broken" on the Qt and difficult to fix. Btw, can you better clarify what you mean by "every touch on the screen results in a MousePressEvent"?

Comment: All pushButtons have installed an eventFilter which handles touchEvents. MousePress events are passed. Now I took a some button and set a graphicsView to visible on the first touch. Ok. The second touch should hide the graphicsView, what will not happen. After the first setting visible, all further touchEvents are recognized as mousePress events from the eventFilter. No more touch events until the application closes. Unfortunately this is true for all pushButtons being touch enabled.

Comment: In order to avoid full requalification of the software I will try to work around this issue in the eventFilter: calling the touch handlers in case of the mousePress event. But I am afraid of side effects in legacy code.

Comment: Instead of installing an event filter on all widgets, consider installing one on the QApplication itself. In any case, please provide a [mre] and at least we'll try to see if there is some logical issue in your implementation.